# Вывод через интерфейс C#

Tags: c#

Требовалось решить задачу об обходе конем доски вида N*N и вывести на экран решение. Алгоритм-то прост, его я реализовал, а вот с выводом возникли проблемы. Практик требует, чтобы вывод был "через интерфейс". Конкретнее ничего, к сожалению, сказать не могу. Я не понимаю, что требуется. Вдруг кто-то знает, что это значит, и сможет объяснить, хотя я понимаю, что шансов мало. Вот функция вывода в консоль, которая не удовлетворяет его

```
   private static void Print(int boardSize, int[,] board)
   {
        for (int x = 0; x < boardSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < boardSize; y++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0:D2} ", board[x, y]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Все, что я понял насчет интерфейсов и данной задачи, так это то, что требуется создать отдельный класс, отнаследовать его. Вот пока единственное, что я понял

```
interface Printer
{
    void Print(string toPrint);
}
class ConsolePrinter : Printer
{
    public static void Print(string format, object arg)
    {
        Console.Write(format, arg);
    }
}
```

Как теперь это (если это конечно правильно) перевести в первую функцию? Просьба не заминусовывать, просто напишите в комментах, что я плохо объянил, попробую рассказать. Если вопрос совсем не логичен, тоже не минусуйте плиз, а просто предупредите

Comment: может практик сбил тебя с толку и имел ввиду gui?

Comment: нет, именно не ГУИшное, а как-то через интерфейс

Comment: - интерфейсы принято называть с буквы I => IPrinter
 - в вашем случае реализация интерфейса выглядит как-то не верно - в интрфейсе метод Print принимает один аргумент, а в реализации почему-то 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, от интерфейса можно унаследовать класс, и это в общем-то основная его функция! Так как никакие функции в интерфейсе не реализуются! Судя по вашей задаче, вам необходимо написать интерфейс, в котором будет Объявлена ваша функция Print, и затем создать свой класс, унаследовать его от данного интерфейса и уже в нем (классе) написать конкретную реализацию функции Print! Думаю выглядеть это должно примерно следующим образом:

```
  interface Printer
  {
      void Print(int boardSize, int[,] board);
  }
  class ConsolePrinter : Printer
  {
      public void Print(int boardSize, int[,] board)
      {
         for (int x = 0; x < boardSize; x++)
          {
              for (int y = 0; y < boardSize; y++)
              {
                  Console.Write("{0:D2} ", board[x, y]);
              }
              Console.WriteLine();
          }
      }
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {   
      Printer printer = new ConsolePrinter();
      // вызываем функцию Print
      printer.Print(int boardSize, int[,] board);
  }
```

Comment: зачем создавать объект, если метод Print всё равно `static`?

Comment: Sorry, не заметил, что он статический (всему виной копипаст)

Comment: благодарю, сейчас нет возможности проверить, завтра посмотрю

Answer (score 2):

Cтатический метод в вашем классе **не имеет ничего общего с интерфейсом** и данный код компилятор не пропустит, так как класс не реализовал интерфейс, а обязан! Метод должен быть НЕ статическим, а экземплярным и вызов примерно таким:

```
Printer printer = new ConsolePrinter(); 
printer.Print(int boardSize, int[,] board);
```

+1 насчет именования -> я бы назвал интерфейс *IPrintable*

Comment: IPrintable => то что принтит себя, какой-то не тот смысл получается

Comment: Про себя в имени нет ничего. Имеется ввиду, что если класс реализует данный интерфейс, то он получает возможность "принта" и все. Таже конвенция в мелкософте: IDisposable, ISerializable....

Comment: да-да таких ``...able`` примеров море, но все они означают именно действие по отношении к себе, возникает когнитивный диссонанс, когда класс реализующий интерфейс IPrintable принтит двумерный массив не имеющий к этому классу никакого отношения

Comment: В этом я согласен, но здесь про архитектуру совсем нет речи, как и смысла в данном интерфейсе. Теоретически данный интерфейс должен реализовывать именно класс, который рассчитывает массивы и сможет сам себя распечатать реализовав нужный метод. К тому же не факт, что вычисления производятся не в ConsolePrinter.

Comment: если подумать, то класс реализующий интерфейс ``IPrintable`` может реализовать и интерфейс ``I_расчёт_обхода_конём_доски_able``, то вы правы

Answer (score 1):

1. Объявляете интерфейс для вывода
2. Передаёте экземпляр интерфейса классу, реализующего алгоритм, через конструктор, и сохраняете в поле этого класса.
3. Вывод на консоль из класса, реализующего алгоритм, делаете через обращение к этому полю с вызовом метода (-ов), объявленного в интерфейсе
4. Создаёте класс, реализующий интерфейс вывода. Например, через консоль.
5. Создаёте экземпляр этого класса, передаёте его классу, реализующему алгоритм.